# Using modulo to determine optimal usage of space. Is there an easier way in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

As an example, let's say we want to see what's the highest utilization when fitting 27.5" wide chairs vs 31.5" wide chairs into a space of 105". The final value I want to see is the highest percentage utilization, not the size of the chair to pick.

I'm doing it this way:

```
[((105 - (105 % 27.5)) / 105), ((105 - (105 % 31.5)) / 105)].max
```

Comment: What doesn't work well? It can be expressed in a shorter form (and easier to read) but it seem correct to me as it is. I would write it as `1 - [105 % 27.5, 105 % 31.5].min / 105` (get the smallest unused space, divide to `105` to express it as fraction of the whole, subtract from `1` to get the used space as fraction of the whole space).

Comment: Thanks @axiac. Sorry, I'm still a Ruby newbie, so I think there is a special Ruby way for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

axiac gave a reasonable answer in the comments above. If you want to know how it might look in idiomatic Ruby, I suggest the following, although it's only one of several possibilities:

```
def best_space_utilization(total_space, widths)
  utilization = widths.map {|w| total_space - (total_space % w) }.max
  utilization / total_space.to_f
end

p best_space_utilization(105, [27.5, 31.5])
# => 0.9
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/Gwe7/2

This could, of course, be reduced to a one-liner, with the corresponding sacrifice of readability: `ws.map {|w| t - (t % w) }.max / t.to_f`

If you wanted a function that returned both the best utilization and the corresponding width, you could do something like this:

```
def best_space_utilization(total_space, widths)
  widths.map do |w|
    utilization_percent = (total_space - (total_space % w)) / total_space
    [ w, utilization_percent ]
  end.max_by(&:last)
end

p best_space_utilization(105, [27.5, 31.5])
# => [31.5, 0.9]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/Gwe7/4